# How make function to progress bar, for different items in BaseAdapter

Tags: java, android, firebase, kotlin, android-listview

I used listview. I have 5 items. When I start program I see only 3. Handler what is for progress bar start working for 3/5 items. I go to see 4,5 item, so i lost from view 1,2 item. 4 and 5 item handler starts working.

```
//Adapter class    

var progress = 0
var gain = myData 
handler = Handler(Handler.Callback {
            progress = progress + speed
            if (progress >= 100) {
                progress = 0
                functionWhatChangeInFirebase(gain) 

            }

            iData.progressBar?.progress = progress

            handler?.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100)

            true 

        })
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0)
```

Problem is when I go back to look at first and second item, handler start "new thread" and progress bar have more that one function, what changed data.

**Edit**
Added Adapter class

```
package com.example.adventurepwr

import android.content.Context
import android.content.res.ColorStateList
import android.graphics.Color
import android.os.Handler
import android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import java.util.ArrayList

class AdapterItem(context: Context, private val itemList: ArrayList<Item>) : BaseAdapter() {


    private val mInflater: LayoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context)


    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {

        val current = itemList[position]


        val item: String = current.item!!
        val level: Int = current.level!!
        val price: Int = current.price!!
        val gain: Int = current.gain!!
        val speed: Int = current.speed!!
        val count: Int = current.count!!


        val view: View

        val iData: ItemsData

        if (convertView == null) {
            view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.content_item, parent, false)
            iData = ItemsData(view)
            view.tag = iData

        } else {
            view = convertView
            iData = view.tag as ItemsData
        }



        iData.name?.text = item
        iData.level?.text = level.toString()
        iData.price?.text = price.toString()
        iData.gain?.text = gain.toString()
        iData.speed?.text = speed.toString()
        iData.count?.text = count.toString() 
        var progress: Int = 0
        var handler: Handler? = null


        iData.lvlButton?.setOnClickListener {

            canUpgrade(price, item)


        }



        handler = Handler(Handler.Callback {
            progress = progress + speed
            if (progress >= 100) {
                progress = 0
                addMoneyNormal(gain)

            }

            iData.progressBar?.progress = progress

            handler?.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100)

            true

        })
        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0)


        return view
    }

    override fun getItem(index: Int): Any {
        return itemList.get(index)
    }

    override fun getItemId(index: Int): Long {
        return index.toLong()
    }

    override fun getCount(): Int {
        return itemList.size
    }


    private class ItemsData(row: View?) {
        val name: TextView? = row!!.findViewById(R.id.name_item) as TextView?
        val level: TextView? = row!!.findViewById(R.id.lvl_Number) as TextView?
        val price: TextView? = row!!.findViewById(R.id.price_number) as TextView?
        val speed: TextView? = row!!.findViewById(R.id.speed) as TextView?
        val gain: TextView? = row!!.findViewById(R.id.gain) as TextView?
        val count: TextView? = row!!.findViewById(R.id.count_number) as TextView?

        val lvlButton: FloatingActionButton? = row!!.findViewById(R.id.lvl_up_button) as FloatingActionButton?

        val progressBar: ProgressBar? = row!!.findViewById(R.id.progressBar) as ProgressBar?
    }


}
```

I go to the main
and do something like this, but i get stackOverflow 8mb

```
fun progress(){

            for (oneRecord in itemList) {

                val item: Item = oneRecord
                item.count=item.count!! + item.speed!!

                if (item.count!!>100){
                    addMoneyNormal(item.gain!!)
                    item.count=0
                }

                Thread.sleep(1000)
            }

            adapterItem.notifyDataSetChanged()
            progress()
        }

        progress()
```

Maybe we can do something with this

Now progressBar.progress = count

Comment: Can you add your list adapter?

Comment: @RKRK Adapter added

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure, but you need to move handler from `getView()` and you should check for each item.

Can you try this:

```
fun testMethod(current) { 
    if(current.count < 4) { 
        return
    }

    handler = Handler(Handler.Callback {
        progress = progress + speed
        if (progress >= 100) {
            progress = 0
            addMoneyNormal(gain)
        }

        iData.progressBar?.progress = progress
        handler?.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, 100)
        true
    })

    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0)
}
```

Comment: Problem is, gain and speed increase, when you play
How it works in clicker games

Answer (score 0):

```
 val myRun = object : Runnable {


            override fun run() {

                for (oneRecord in mUploads) {

                    val item: Item = oneRecord
                    item.count = item.count!! + item.speed!!

                    if (item.count!! >= 100) {
                        item.count = 0
                        addMoneyNormal(item.gain!!)
                    }


                }

                adapterItem.notifyDataSetChanged()
                this@MainActivity.mHandler.postDelayed(this, 100)

            }

        }

        myRun.run()
```

So i use this in my main class

in adapter i used, that count is progression

For now I dont see any bugs